# Save results to a text file in PHP

Tags: php

First of all I want you to know that my knowledge about coding is very very low, almost 0. I have done some coding using tutorials, but now I am stuck :(

I have this code:

```
$fp = fopen('myfile.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, "Kilometrii : $a. Consum : $b. Pret : $c.Cost : $num4.\"); 
fclose($fp);
```

This code is doing some calculation and then it saves the results to a text file. My problem is that it saves only one result; if I do a second calculation it overwrites the first result and so on. My second problem is that the result is saved on a single line.

Example:

```
(Kilometrii : -88687. Consum : -148.06115890717. Pret : 0.00024164007585046.Cost : 31.73.\ ).
```

I want to show the results one above the other and separate multiple calculations by a bigger space. Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Open file with another mode

Comment: I’d encourage retitling this to clarify what you need help with. Maybe “How do I save each of my results to their own file?”, or, if you want it all in one file, “How do I save every result of a loop to a single file?”

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the with the `w` flag which truncates the file to zero length. You probably want to open it with `a` (append mode) to not erase the file and put the cursor at the end of the file. You can see all the modes on the [fopen manual page](https://www.php.net/fopen)

Example:

```
$fp = fopen('myfile.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, "Kilometrii : $a. Consum : $b. Pret : $c.Cost : $num4.\n"); 
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append with `a` and you have an errant backslash `\`, but you can use it to add a newline `\n`:

```
$fp = fopen('myfile.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, "Kilometrii : $a. Consum : $b. Pret : $c.Cost : $num4.\n"); 
fclose($fp);
```

If viewing in a browser you'll need a `<br>` instead or run it through `nl2br()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
fopen('myfile.txt', 'a') instead of 'w'. Including a link for further reference
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php